# C# GetKeyDown Won't Run Under Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get `Game();` to load again whenever the up arrow is pressed but it won't run. This is some of the code. Whenever the up arrow is pressed, I just want it to run `Game();` and I can't figure out why it's not. I'm pretty new to programming so it might just be a simple problem and I'm just being stupid.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;

    string playerChoice = "Higher";


    void Update () {
        if (playerChoice == "Higher") {
            Game ();
        }
    }

    void Game () {
        text.text = "Is your number " + compGuess + "?\n\n Press Up Arrow for higher, Down Arrow for lower and Space for equal to.";
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            playerChoice = "Higher";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Unity Editor in the top-left corner go to Edit > Project Settings > Input. There you will find some Axes and you can add new ones by changing the Size variable or just edit one. To change the key just edit the positive keys. Negative keys are returned when the value is -1 and positive 1. Alt is an alternative key that you can use like maybe W. For up arrow type up, for down arrow down, for right arrow type right and for left arrow type left. Then in your code instead of using `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {}` use `if(Input.GetAxis("AxisName")) {}` also the axis name is sensitive so you must use spaces and upper or lower cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this hard for you. I don't think you understand how the `Update` function is called. Use `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` to get the name of the current scene, then `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);` to **load** the scene when the up **arrow** is pressed. You **only** need to check if the up arrow key is pressed in the Update function. Your code is redundant. Below is a fix for your code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Check if up key is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            //Call the Game() function because up key was pressed
            Game();
        }
    }

    void Game()
    {
        //text.text = "Is your number " + compGuess + "?\n\n Press Up Arrow for higher, Down Arrow for lower and Space for equal to.";
        Debug.Log("Up Key Pressed!...Re-Loading Level");

        //Get name of current scene
        string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;

        //Load current Scene again
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);

    }
}
```